# iSeries endless signon loop in MS Access VBA

Tags: odbc, ibm-midrange

Morning all!

I have one user out of 150 that experiences an endless loop of iSeries signon prompts.  We have a database written in MS Access VBA that connects to our iSeries that is used to track defects.  When the user enters either a work order, purchase order or part number, there is an ODBC query to the iSeries that pulls some information such as vendor name, customer part name, and item commodity code.

This application has been used for just under 3 years and hasn't had any issues of the sort.  I've configured and reconfigured the user's ODBC settings several times and have even been able to duplicate the error on a newer workstation but only when using the user's credentials. This signon loop does not occur with any other user.  I'm out of ideas....has anyone encountered something similar?

Specifics:

- Windows 7
- iSeries OS/400 v6r1
- iSeries ODBC driver v 13.00.01.00

Thanks in advance!

Matt

Comment: Sounds like the signon is failing and your application doesn't do anything but retry.  You could turning on tracing to see if you can find out any more info.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1017796

Comment: Is there anything different with the user's password.  I seem to remember some issues for example with Mixed Case passwords depending on some system values.

Comment: I turned on the tracing and saw an error:  SQL0204 - MSYSCONF in AMFLIB type *FILE not found.  I've never seen this...

Comment: Scott - I changed the user's password to all lower case and one number, have the same issue.  Even upgraded the iAccess client to v7r1 but to no avail.

Comment: It appears the MSYSCONF file is something the MS Jet engine uses and can't find....got my consultants looking into it.  What a pain!